# Relate PSVI GetSchemaInfo to the XSD Validation Error ValidationEventArgs.Message

Tags: .net-4.0, xml-validation, xsd-validation

I have a question about Microsoft's MSDN documentation for the [Extenstions.GetSchemaInfo Method (XElement)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342577.aspx) for .Net framework 4.0.

I want to know if there's a way from within the

```
Private Sub DumpInvalidNodes(ByVal el As XElement)
   If el.GetSchemaInfo.Validity <> XmlSchemaValidity.Valid Then
     ...
   End If
End Sub
```

Code to get the ValidationEventArgs.Message for the invalid node.  This example works fine when you have numbered XML nodes like in the example: GrandChild1, GrandChild2.  You can tell which invalid node is producing the validation errors by site.  But when you have XML without numbered nodes, e.g.

```
<Root>
    <Child>
        <GrandChild>AAA</GrandChild>
        <GrandChild>ZZZ</GrandChild>
        <GrandChild>ZZZ</GrandChild>
    </Child>
</Root>
```

you get output that looks like this:

```
(1)Validating doc1 ... 
(2)The 'GrandChild' element is invalid - The value 'ZZZ' is invalid according to its datatype 'GCType' - The Enumeration constraint failed. 
(3)The 'GrandChild' element is invalid - The value 'ZZZ' is invalid according to its datatype 'GCType' - The Enumeration constraint failed. 
(4)doc1 did not validate 
(5)Invalid Element /Root 
(6)Invalid Element /Root/Child 
(7)Invalid Element /Root/Child/GrandChild 
(8)Invalid Element /Root/Child/GrandChild
```

I wanted a way to tell that line (7) referred to the ErrorMessage in line (2).

I have an XML document that I'm running XSD validation against as this article shows and I wanted to parse the ValidationEventArgs.Message into a more user friendly message for complex data types.  I'd like to do this in the DumpInvalidNodes() method because I have access to the invalid Node and can obtain other information from the node (like an ID) that the user can use to find and fix the validation problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way for you would be to modify the original code and instead of doing the node dumping after, do it in the validation handler; it'll give you the validation message and the node at the same time (simply cast the sender to an XObject and deal with it as you need).

For XML loaded from files or strings you could also use this MSDN article [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb538457.aspx). Additional hints to the user, such as line number and column position, could also be useful.

Comment: I tried accessing properties like LineNumber and they were always empty but I don't think I was correctly capturing the XObject in the validation handler.  It's been awhile since I reviewed this project so I will review it and see if this will give me some more properties.  Thanks!

Comment: The line info is empty, unless you configure the options to get it. You have to do it explicitly, by default is not there. See this [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb538457.aspx) for an example.